# Out of Memory Error - When Adding Markers in GoogleMap and making Bitmap

Tags: android, out-of-memory, google-maps-android-api-2, android-bitmap

This error doesn't happen when the map loads but after moving the map position to other locations and new markers appear...

Here is Stacktrace:

```
08-29 15:11:38.061: E/art(6669): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with 3486016 free bytes"
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2298
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669): Process: com.---.---, PID: 6669
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with 3486016 free bytes
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:810)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:787)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:754)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at opl.a(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at opp.a(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at opp.a(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at opp.b(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at oow.a(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at ope.a(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at okm.a(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at ojx.a(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at ojx.b(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at otq.k(Unknown Source)
08-29 15:11:38.201: E/AndroidRuntime(6669):     at otq.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is how I create the Bitmap:

```
   public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {

        try {
            if (v.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0) {
                v.measure(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  Bitmap bActual = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bActual, 120, 120, true);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
                v.draw(c);
                return b;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It is called in my doInBackground in my `AsyncTask`, like:

```
  MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(LOC)
                        .snippet(user)
                        .title(name)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(loadBitmapFromView(v1)));
```

In `onPostExecute`, I add new markers that the database find that are not already showing.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < markers.get(i).nl.size() - 1; i++) {
                Marker m = googleMap.addMarker(markers.get(i).mO.get(i));
                markerIdMap.put(m, markers.get(i).nl.get(i));
            }
```

Here is how I set up my map:

*Other tidbits:*

```
    googleMap.setClustering(new ClusteringSettings().enabled(false)
            .addMarkersDynamically(true));

    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cp) {

            LOC = cp.target;
            MainActivity.mLongitude = LOC.longitude;
            MainActivity.mLatitude = LOC.latitude;

            if (!running) {
                new NearLocationsTask().execute();
            }
        }
    });
```

And I am using `android-map-extensions`

Comment: I am facing the same issue. can you please tell me what is "v1"' here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really to create an empty bitmap and the scale it:

Bitmap bActual = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bActual, 120, 120, true);

If you have a lot of markers, maybe you are trying to allocate too many bitmaps.

Comment: I think you are right.  There is faulty logic in my code that  adds same markers for every camera change. Not just new one. Probably adds up resources really fast.

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago, if you just add the same markers without removing the previous ones, it is very easy to crash the app by lack of memory.